# Is it possible to get to the Proxy Falls in Oregon without a car?

Tags: public-transport, oregon

I do not drive but I would like to see these falls. Is this possible somehow?

Comment: Rent a car? Hitchhike? There's no public transit within 100km of there!

Comment: @MichaelHampton:  Surprisingly, there *is* public transit within 100km of there — see Carl's answer.  It's still not close by, though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are plenty of buses to Eugene from other cities.

From Eugene there is a bus to the McKenzie River Ranger Station a few times a day https://goo.gl/maps/UypiSvpMkk12

From there, its a 10 mile hike. Could make a nice little backpacking overnight trip.

Comment: Good find!  [Here's the route info from the transit authority's website.](https://www.ltd.org/system-map/route_91/)